# React Native Distinguish between iPhone 11 Pro vs iPhone 12 Mini

Tags: ios, react-native, iphone12

Both devices share the same screen size 375×812. How can I determine which is which? I need to access the status bar height which are different for iPhone 11 and Mini(44 and 50).
Thanks,

Comment: Maybe [getDeviceId](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getdeviceid) from [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did not find any solution with iphone 12, but you can try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height package

Comment: yeah need an iPhone 12 solution.

Comment: @zachary, once try with this package